How to get the second stationary point condition corresponding to intercept when using the augmented weight vector and augmented design matrix in SVM?
Below is the formulation I got for SVM when using the equation of classifier as w.x + b = 0

I want to know why I am not getting the second stationary condition i.e. summation over i from 1 to n of (alpha_i*y_i) = 0 when I use the augmented weight vector that includes the intercept and the augmented design matrix(shape nx(d+1)) obtained by adding a column of ones in the beginning. This is to say that when I used w.x = 0 as the equation of the classifier and proceeded with SVM formulation then I did not get the second stationary condition.
